# .class == .class vs .class.toString() vs .class.toString()

Tags: java, class

I was playing around with Classname.class and Classname.class.toString() and found something unusual.

.class seems to equate to .class when run on the same Class. Although .class.toString() **does not** equate to the .class.toString() on the same class. Why would this be.

Please see my code below

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        if(String.class.toString() == String.class.toString())
            System.out.println("toString(): Yes they are the same");
        else
            System.out.println("toString(): They are not the same ?");

        System.out.println("=============================");

        if(String.class == String.class)
            System.out.println(".class: Yes they are the same");
        else
            System.out.println(".class: They are not the same");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sh-4.3# javac HelloWorld.java                                                                                                                            
sh-4.3# java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld       

toString(): They are not the same ?                                                                                                                      
=============================                                                                                                                            
.class: Yes they are the same
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't use == operator to compare strings. Use .equals() method instead.

Comment: Oh god ! Wonder how I missed that !

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect that one `toString()` invocation would return the exact same object as a second invocation? Neither `Object.toString()` nor `Class.toString()` specifies in their Javadoc API documentation that the same `String` object will be returned in successive invocations.

Without a reason to do otherwise, one must assume the default contract that `String` instances must be compared with `equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, You're comparing references, not string content, and the references are not equals.

```
String.class.toString() == String.class.toString()
```

You must compare with equals:

```
String.class.toString().equals(String.class.toString())
```

Or You can compare with advance feature of string, like this:

```
String.class.toString().intern() == String.class.toString().intern()
```